# How to load android system native library

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, java-native-interface, native

I wrote a c++ native library that has some dependencies (most notably Qt) and i want to call it via jni from a standard Android Java App. I am currently using Android Studio but that is not really mandatory.

The libs have some system dependencies like libz, liblog and (as c++ runtime) libgnustl_shared.

Now, my question is: how do i load these libraries? for current testing i have added them in the jniLibs folder of my app but that is not (i think) the correct way to deal with this kind of scenario.

my current code in the main activity is like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared");
        System.loadLibrary("log");
        System.loadLibrary("opus");
        System.loadLibrary("z");
        System.loadLibrary("Qt5Core");
        System.loadLibrary("Qt5Network");
        System.loadLibrary("mynative-lib");
    }
...
}
```

If i remove liblog or libz or libgnustl_shared i get an UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with what you have right now?

Comment: @JBL, maybe nothing, i am not that experienced in android programming yet, i thought that since those were "system" libraries i would have to link to those instead of providing my own in the apk. Besides, if i deploy the ones found in the android SDK which ones should i deploy? i.e. if i target min android version to be 23, should i provide the ones from platform 23 ($NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-23/arch-x86/usr/lib/liblog.so) i think, right?

Comment: I don't remember how we picked the `gnustl` lib on the project I worked on, but that would seem the correct way indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid possibility. There's still the risk that when you add libraries you might link them in the wrong order if you don't pay attention.

You could potentially have a more condensed version should you link statically all your dependencies into `mynative-lib`.

You would end up with a shorter loading code:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared");
    System.loadLibrary("mynative-lib-with-deps");
}
```

This would also reduce the size of your `jniLibs` folder (and thus APK) as statically linking your dependencies into your libraries will potentially reduce how much of your dependencies will be embedded into your app.